# Custom rendering for text with special syntax

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a text gathered from API and it consists of custom syntax. I display it using TextView but I need to render special part of the text and convert those text into elements. An example of a text is below.

```
Oh, that's great idea! Check (user: someuser)'s answer for this.
You can as well look at (ref: a forum post title) or:

(ref: another forum post)

This is a hint for you! (hint: should be displayed as a mini icon
but when clicked, a tooltip should be opened)

Here is a spoiler for you.

---- spoiler ----
some spoiler. this text should not be displayed directly but it should be
converted to a button element. When the button is clicked, this text should
be shown
---- spoiler ----
```

So, I need to convert `(user: someuser)` into a link in the view which will be shown as "someuser" but when clicked, it will open a new intent. For `(ref: topic)` keyword, it's the same. When I hit `spoiler`, I want to make it a nice button indicating that it's a spoiler and when user clicks, it will expand.

How can I parse this text and show correctly in a view? I don't have problem with parsing but my problem is displaying those elements in the view.

### Methods I Tried

I tried WebView instead of TextView thinking that I can convert those into HTML/Js but the performance was terrible. Although I use RecycleView and ViewHolder, WebView is simply an overkill. I need to use some kind of a TextView but with the elements I would like to have.

I also looked at custom HTML tag handling with TextView (thinking I can convert those legacy tags into html) but I failed to see how I can insert button for spoiler tag or insert custom elements like tooltip for hint.

Thank you!

Comment: you should read about `Spannable` interface

Comment: thank you. It looks like the correct way to start researching on this problem. I am reading Spannable interface now, trying to find open source projects, and examples.